# Mock method attribute python throws AttributionError

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following method:

```
def get_countries(cities):
     prefix = os.getenv("PREFIX")
     ...
     ...
```

I would like to mock this prefix attribute (because I didn't find a way to mock only one key in `os.getenv("PREFIX")`  and `@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"PREFIX": "P"})` - would mock the whole dict and there could be other keys which I want to keep.

So I wrote the following:

```
@mock.patch.object("get_countries", "prefix", "P")
    def test_get_aggregated_performance_records_countries_min_spend():
     ...
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: get_countries does not have the attribute 'prefix'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`prefix` isn't a property of the `get_countries` function.  It is a function scoped variable, that is enclosed in `get_countries` but it's not a Property of `get_countries` :)

If patching the `os.environ` is unacceptable, you could refactor to expose `prefix` as an argument:

```
def get_countries(cities, prefix=os.getenv("PREFIX")):
     ...
     ...
```

making it trivial to provide a value for unit tests.

---

Additionally if you `patch`ed `os.environ`, it should only affect the current test case.  How many keys do you need to specify for a single test?

Comment: I prefer to use mock and not modify my code for the tests. is there a way to mock function scoped variable?
Regarding the os env question - it means that we need to maintain this patch if we plan in the future to use more sys env that in other cases, their value doesn't impact the test.